# Can damaged NVME SSD be repaired if it cannot be mounted?

Tags: macos, ssd

I recently decided to upgrade my 2019 iMac model 19.1 with both SATA and NVME PCIE 3.0 SSD.

SATA was OK but o/s Ventura complained the 2TB Adata SX8600 was incompatible. I persevered loaded o/s Ventura on the NVME and ran Black Magic to confirm speed of operation which was Read 3125 Write 2754.

What worried me was bootup times of 13 secs for the SATA drive compared to 47 secs for the 4x faster NVMe. In particular, when booting from the NVME, there were pauses and hesitations which I interpreted as initialising problems - which would explain both incompatibility and slow bootup.

I decided to erase the NVME and try reformatting. Disk Utility threw up an erase failure notice. Since then, the NVME would not mount and therefore disk would not respond to First Aid, Erase & Reformat or Restore.
Disk Utility now recognises the disk as Uninitialised at 1.07GB (not 2TB)!

SMART notices fail to work on the disk saying: Smart support is ambiguous; A mandatory Smart command failed.

Can this NVME be repaired or have I killed it stone dead?

Comment: Sure seems like it's dead. You can try another tool, e.g., https://alternativeto.net/software/diskgenius/?platform=mac , putting it in an external enclosure, but don't have high hopes.

Comment: Thank you Dr Pippik, the site you referred me to led to TestDisk, a Terminal app which I shall use to test disk recovery. Best Wishes and thanks Australopithicus

Comment: I have installed TestDisk into Homebrew correctly but am out of my depth with Terminal instructions taken from - https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step. Can someone help me create the correct string for re-mounting ‘lost’ disk please.